# After resizing google cloud instance cant connect to external ip address

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-resource-manager

I upgraded my server instance to have more ram. Now I can't connect to it via FileZilla or access the website it hosted. I can only connect to its view button in the Google Cloud Console labeled ssh.

Comment: Would you please share specific error message?

Comment: Please move it to the Serverfault Stack Exchange. This is for coding related issues. You will find more help there. Also, make sure that your question is clear because I didn't understand much.

Comment: Most likely the public IP address changed. https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ip-addresses#externaladdresses

Comment: I just get can't access this website in my browser via timeout error.
And when i try to use fillezilla with working(worked before resize) ssh i also got timeout 
error.

Comment: @Somone please check your Public IP address as mentioned by (JohnHanley) as after restart public IP will be changed if you are not using reserved IP.

Answer (score 3):

Unless configured, External IPs of Compute Engine VMs are ephemeral. If you view 'VM instance details' External IP likely states this.

https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ip-addresses#externaladdresses
https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ip-addresses#ephemeraladdress

[image]